# remove yaxis values from FacetGrid in seaborn

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

trying to remove the yaxis values.

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'row':['a']*9 + ['b']*9 + ['c']*9,                                        
                        'col': ['fft','krn','bycp']*9,                                          
                        'val':np.random.randn(27)})                                             
    print 'data', d
```

Tried to grab figure not work.

```
    #f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)                                            
    f,ax = plt.subplots()                                                                       
    r= d['row'].unique()                                                                        
    (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5) = sns.color_palette("husl", 6)[:5]                                     
    g = sns.FacetGrid(d, col='col', row='row',size=.7, aspect=5, palette="husl",margin_titles=True)
    g.map(sns.rugplot,'val',height=.12)                                                         
    print sns.axes_style()
```

despine does not remove the values

```
 sns.despine(left='False')                                                                   
    g.fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=.1, hspace=.02);                                               
    g.set_axis_labels(['a','b','c'], 'values');


    ax = plt.gcf().axes
    ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

    ax.set_visible(False)
    plt.show()
```

`plt.gcf().axes` give `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'axes'`

`get_yaxis()` does nothing.

How to remove yaxis values from FacetGrid in seaborn?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try calling `g.set(yticks=[])` after you plot. This just loops through the axes and calls `ax.set_yticks([])` on each of them.

This will also turn off the ticks/grid lines, which I assume you want for this plot, but if you just want to turn the labels off you can do `g.set(yticklabels=[])`.

Comment: thank for the help! Also I would like to help expand the explanation of your good api; for example the set() function, and a little more what is under the hood.  I am awful grateful, but feel horrible having to ask basic questions regarding the fundamentals of how things are working.  When I finish this project, maybe I can read your src more completely and not expose/expand your api , but help with those who are new to matplotlib... again thankyou !!!

Comment: It's documented [here](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/axis_grids.html#subsetting-data-with-facetgrid), but yes `FacetGrid` is complicated and there is lots you'd have to know about it use it fully.